# Vue - What is the common practice for canvas animation?

Tags: vue.js, canvas

I wonder if my approach is a good way of drawing canvas animation in Vue.js

It works but I'm not sure I'm doing it right.

Since I'm using javascript Class for making a circle array of Canvas, I made a separate javascript file for that and imported. (2d context had to be passed to the class)

The approach is as below.

Canvas.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <canvas id='myCanvas' width='500' height='500'></canvas>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Circle from './canvasClass/Circle.js';
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            canvas:null,
            x:null,
            y:null,
            circleArr:[]
        }
    },

    mounted(){
        let canvas = document.querySelector('#myCanvas');
        this.canvas = canvas.getContext('2d');
    },

    created(){
        window.addEventListener('click',this.createCircle)
        this.draw()
    },

    unmounted() {
    window.removeEventListener('click', this.createCircle) 
    },
    methods:{
        createCircle(e){
            this.circleArr.push(
                new Circle(e.offsetX,e.offsetY,this.canvas)
            )
        },
        draw(){
            window.requestAnimationFrame(this.draw);

            this.circleArr.forEach((d)=>{
                d.animate()
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

The separate javscript file for the circle class is

```
export default class Circle {
    constructor(xpos, ypos, context) {
        this.xpos = xpos;
        this.ypos = ypos;
        this.context = context;
    }
    draw() {
        this.context.beginPath();
        this.context.arc(this.xpos, this.ypos, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        this.context.stroke();
    }
    move() {
        this.xpos += 0.5;
        this.ypos += 0.5
    }
    animate() {
        this.draw()
        this.move()
    }
}
```

Can anyone let me know if my approach is an okay way to draw canvas animation in Vue?
If it's not a good way can anyone give me a better suggestion?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You are in the right way.

Here are more useful npm modules, though

[Vue Konva](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-konva)